# The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial? I believe I need to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem which I understand to be

The characteristic polynomial of a linear operator annihilates it

Answer (score 6):

The Matrix $A$ annihilates the minimal and characteristic polynomial $\mu_A$ and $\chi_A$. We write the Euclidean division of $\chi_A$ by $\mu_A$:

$$\chi_A(x)=\mu_A(x)Q(x)+R(x)$$
with $\deg(R)<\deg(\mu_A)$ so if $R\ne0$ we find a polynomial with degree less than the degree of $\mu_A$ such that $A$ annihilates it and this contradicts the definition of $\mu_A$.

Comment: This is neat. My textbook somehow argues with the ggt and then that the ggt can we written (through Euklids algo) as a sum of both which are zero (same endgame as your proof).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Perform division with remainder for the two polynomials. Evaluate the remainder at the given endomorphism.